# Android - BluetoothSocket.accept() without client-side app

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to do an Android app that is able to send data over bluetooth, in a manner similar to "GPS over BT". The feature of this app is that it is able to connect to a device B, without having any bluetooth client software running on it.

Summarizing, what i want is:

- device A became discoverable, acting as a Server.
- device B pairs with A, if not previously paired.
- <strike>device B try to connect to device A, using system bluetooth settigs (Settings -> Wireless and Networks -> Bluetooth)</strike>
- device A and B are able to talk, in particular A start sending data <strike>to B</strike> over the air (regardless of being paired with any device).
- device B since has been paired with A uses data received via Bluetooth with programs like "Bluetooth GPS" or integrated GPS bluetooth source selector (CM 10).

  ```
  private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
  private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

  public AcceptThread() {
      // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
      // because mmServerSocket is final
      BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
      try {
          // MyUUID is 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, neither other random choices helped;
          // bt is the BluetoothAdapter;
          tmp = bt.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("BluetoothService", MyUUID);
      } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      mmServerSocket = tmp;
  }

  public void run() {
      BluetoothSocket socket = null;

          try {
              socket = mmServerSocket.accept();  //It never goes beyond this function
          } catch (IOException e) {
              //break;
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          // If a connection was accepted
          if (socket != null) {
              // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
              manageConnectedSocket(socket);
              try {
                  mmServerSocket.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

  }
  ```

Obviously it blocks at `BluetoothServerSocket.accept()`.

As you can see this is nothing more than the example in the [Android Bluetooth Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). I tried to change from secure to unsecure connection but it didn't help.

Having the MAC of the potential listener may help? Directly i would like to avoid to install a client side app, and being able to send bluetooth data to all devices that are able to see my messages (those paired with me), ie. by sending NMEA messages and acting as an external GPS.

Sorry for my bad english.

Tested on a Nexus 4, 4.4.2

---

More or less i've managed to write a working activity that accept connections without need for a clientside app. I will tidy a bit the code and then i will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet that is working for me; it's very badly written, use as a base example
it's based on BluetoothChat example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
    private static final boolean D = true; //is debugging enabled
    // Message types sent from the BluetoothService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    // BT Status
    public static final int STATUS_OFF = 0;
    public static final int STATUS_ON = 1;
    public static final int STATUS_DISCOVERABLE = 2;
    public static final int STATUS_NO_DEVICE = 3;
    public static final int STATUS_CONNECTING = 4;
    public static final int STATUS_CONNECTED = 5;
    public static final int STATUS_ERROR = 6;
    // Key names received from the BluetoothService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";
    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT = 0x1e;
    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // String buffer for outgoing messages
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    // Member object for the chat services
    private BluetoothService mBtService = null;
    private boolean useBT;
    private int statusBT;
    private boolean isBtAskingDiscoverability;
    private final BroadcastReceiver bcReceiverBt4Discoverability = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {
                if(D) Log.d(TAG,"BroadCast Received: bcReceiverBt4Discoverability");
                if(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE ) {
                    MainActivity.this.setBTStatus(STATUS_DISCOVERABLE);
                    return;
                }
                MainActivity.this.setBTStatus(STATUS_ON);
            }
        }
    };
    private final BroadcastReceiver bcReceiverBt4StateChanged = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                if(D) Log.d(TAG,"BroadCast Received: bcReceiverBt4StateChanged");
                if(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON ) {
                    MainActivity.this.setBTStatus(STATUS_CONNECTING);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate: Bluetooth is not available");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)).setChecked(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());
        registerBroadcastReceivers();
        ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()) {
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnClick: ensureDiscoverable()");
                    ensureDiscoverable();
                }
                else
                    turnOffBT(true);
            }
        });
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendMessage("Test");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "++ ON START ++");
        if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnStart: ensureDiscoverable()");
        ensureDiscoverable();
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
        super.onResume();
        if(useBT) {
            if(mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnResume: ensureDiscoverable()");
                    ensureDiscoverable();
                } else if(mBtService == null) {
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnResume: initService()");
                    initService();
                }
            }
            if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnResume: ReUseBT()");
            restartBT();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterBroadcastReceivers();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnDestroy: turnOffBT(true)");
        turnOffBT(true);
        if(mBtService != null) {
            mBtService.stop();
            mBtService = null;
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter != null)
            mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode = " + requestCode
                + "; resultCode = " + resultCode);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT:
            {
                isBtAskingDiscoverability = false;
                if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) { // original 0x1e
                    useBT = true;
                    ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)).setChecked(true);
                    if(mBtService == null) {
                        if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnActivityResult (REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT): initService()");
                        initService();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                useBT = false;
                ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1)).setChecked(false);
                if(D) Log.d(TAG,"OnActivityResult (REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT): SetBTStatus(STATUS_OFF)");
                setBTStatus(STATUS_OFF);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void restartBT() {
        if(mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if(mBtService != null) {
                if(mBtService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_NONE ||
                        mBtService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_LOST/* ||
                        mBtService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_FAILED*/) {
                    try {
                        if(D) Log.d(TAG,"restartBT: mBtService.start()");
                        mBtService.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to start BluetoothService", e);
                        if(D) Log.d(TAG,"restartBT (Exception): setBTStatus(STATUS_OFF)");
                        setBTStatus(STATUS_OFF);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(D) Log.d(TAG,"restartBT: initService()");
                initService();
            }
        }
    }
    private synchronized void ensureDiscoverable() { //
        if(this.isBtAskingDiscoverability) return;
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() || 
                ((statusBT != STATUS_DISCOVERABLE) && (statusBT != STATUS_CONNECTED))) {
            if(mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
                this.isBtAskingDiscoverability = true;
                Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);//discoverableIntent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.adapter.extra.DISCOVERABLE_DURATION", mPC.time_to_discoverable);
                startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT);
            } else {
                if(mBtService == null)
                    initService();
            }
        } else {
            if(mBtService == null)
                initService();
        }
    }
    private synchronized void initService() {
        if(mBtService != null) return;
        mBtService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }
    protected void setBTStatus(int status) {
        statusBT = status;
        switch(status) {
            default: {
                mConnectedDeviceName = null;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error, status " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case STATUS_OFF: {
                mConnectedDeviceName = null;
                Toast.makeText(this, "BT turned OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case STATUS_NO_DEVICE: {
                mConnectedDeviceName = null;
                Toast.makeText(this, "No device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case STATUS_CONNECTED: {
                mConnectedDeviceName = null;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to device " + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case STATUS_ON: {
                if(mConnectedDeviceName == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bt ON; No device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to device " + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATUS_CONNECTING:
            {
                mConnectedDeviceName = null;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void SendMessage(String[] message) {
        if((mBtService == null) ||(mBtService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED))
            return;
        for(String string: message) {
            if(string.length() > 0) {
                byte[] send = string.getBytes();
                mBtService.write(send);
                mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
    private void SendMessage(String message) {
        if((mBtService == null) || (mBtService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED))
            return;
        if(message.length() > 0) {
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mBtService.write(send);
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0x0);
        }
    }
    private void turnOffBT(boolean statusBT) {
        if((statusBT) && (mBtService != null)) {
            mBtService.stop();
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
    private void registerBroadcastReceivers() {
        registerReceiver(bcReceiverBt4StateChanged, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
        registerReceiver(bcReceiverBt4Discoverability, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED));
    }
    private void unregisterBroadcastReceivers() {
        unregisterReceiver(bcReceiverBt4StateChanged);
        unregisterReceiver(bcReceiverBt4Discoverability);
    }
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: {
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE: {
                        setBTStatus(STATUS_ON);
                        return;
                    }
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED: {
                        setBTStatus(STATUS_CONNECTED);
                        return;
                    }
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING: {
                        setBTStatus(STATUS_CONNECTING);
                        return;
                    }
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN: {
                        setBTStatus(STATUS_DISCOVERABLE);
                        return;
                    }
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_LOST: {
                        restartBT();
                    }
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_FAILED:
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error - BT STATE_FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Then I supported that activity with this class

```
public class BluetoothService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
    private static final boolean D = true;  //is debugging enabled
    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothService";
    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
    public static final int STATE_LOST = 4;
    public static final int STATE_FAILED = 5;
    private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    public BluetoothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        this.mHandler = handler;
        this.mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.mState = 0;
    }
    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }
    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }
    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }
    private void connectionFailed() {
        //setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        setState(STATE_FAILED);
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    private void connectionLost() {
        //setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        setState(STATE_LOST);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, SPP_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Connection Accepted");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Connection Accepted, State: " + mState);
                        switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                byte cr = 0xd;
                byte lf = 0xa;

                mmOutStream.write(cr);
                mmOutStream.write(lf);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```